# Scraping with Selenium. for page in range() issue

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape on ethplorer.io. I want to scrape many pages. My code is like this. But it scrapes page(11) three times. range(11,14) I couldn't understand why?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

 
base_url = "https://ethplorer.io/tr/address/0xf87e31492faf9a91b02ee0deaad50d51d56d5d4d#pageSize=100&tab=tab-holders&holders="

results=[]

for page_number in range(11,14):
        url = base_url+str(page_number)
        driver.get(url)
        data = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "local-link")
        for x in data:
                results.append(x.text)

driver.quit

with open("all_data.txt" , "w") as file:
        for x in results:
                file.write(x + "\n")
```

Comment: Update the question with the output you expect and the output do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have applied some modifications to your code to have it working through the several pages you are calling and to capture the text within the hyperlinks I assume you are targeting, please check below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())


 
url = "https://ethplorer.io/tr/address/0xf87e31492faf9a91b02ee0deaad50d51d56d5d4d#pageSize=100&tab=tab-holders&holders=11" # Here we are calling the first page we need, which is page #11 in this case.
xpath = "//div[@id='token-holders-tab']//div[@id='address-token-holders']//div[@class='block']//table//tr//td//a[contains(@class,'local-link')]"
driver.get(url)
data =driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='token-holders-tab']//div[@id='address-token-holders']//div[@class='block']//table//tr//td//a[contains(@class,'local-link')]")
results=[]

for page_number in range(12,15): # Range should start from the next page (page # 12 in this case). Range end with last page you need + 2, in this case you need to scrape from 11 untill 13 ,so rage end should be 15.
        for x in data: # On first round it will get page # 11 data.
            results.append(x.text)
        nextPage = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='token-holders-tab']//tr[contains(@class,'paginationFooter')]//A[@class='page-link'][text()='"+str(page_number)+"']")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", nextPage)
        time.sleep(3)
        data =driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='token-holders-tab']//div[@id='address-token-holders']//div[@class='block']//table//tr//td//a[contains(@class,'local-link')]")

driver.quit

with open("all_data.txt" , "w") as file:
        for x in results:
                file.write(x + "\n")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, File "c:\Users\engin\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Python\script4.py", line 23, in <module>
    for x in data:
NameError: name 'data' is not defined

Comment: I have modified the code to fix the error. sorry I forget one line. please try again engin d.

Comment: thank u very much. code worked. But it scrape page 11-12-13. ---for page_number in range(12,15): --- must it scrape 12-13-14? or we say url=page=11 may be it must scrape 11-12-13-14. what are you thinking?

Comment: @engind. Tell me plz which pages you need ? so, I can better explain it to you.

Comment: In fact, it is constantly changing, depending on the situation. Shouldn't this code normally work like this? when we give a range(1,10) it gives me=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 pages

Comment: @engind. Yes it should work on any range. I have added comments to help you better understand the logic. in `url` you need to specify the webpage at the first page you need. page#11. and then  modify the range to specify where to stop as per I mentioned in the comment I added to the code. since this is working for your, please mark as Answered.

Comment: Thank u. I understand.But I didnt understand why range(x,y) y-2 it scrape? Which code cause this.

Comment: @engind In Python range(x,y)  y is not included. So, it's y-1. Range(12,15) will make three iterations(12,13,14). In my code the first iteration 'for page_number in range(12,15)' we will extract page # 11 data and then we will call page # 12. On the second iteration, we will extract page # 12 data and then we will call page # 13. In the third iteration we will get page # 13 and call page #14 .Finish. The loop ends without getting page # 14 data. Thus, we set y to 15 but we extracted data until page #13 only without getting page #14 data. That's why I mentioned (y-2).

Comment: @engind let's say you need to extrat data from page # 5 until page # 10. Modify my code by setting 'url' last number to 5 instead of 11, and change range(12,15) to be range(6,12) . This will get data from pages # 5 until  page #10. I hope it's clear to you now.

Comment: I really unnderstood. Thank u very much again.

Comment: @engind. most welcome. please mark my answer as accepted or vote it up if you think it was helpful.